# Create a list of objects for testing

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create N objects in a fluent way? Something like:

```
(new Conversion(random.Next(80, 120), random.NextItem(x.Units)).Generate(2000);
```

I am trying to create random objects to populate a database for testing.

And I have a lot of properties where I need to do this so I would like to avoid having for loops everywhere.

Does anyone knows any tool for this?

Comment: You might also want to consider either [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) or [Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx), assuming you are doing some dependency injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Range`:

```
List<Conversion> conversions = Enumerable.Range(1, 2000)
    .Select(i => new Conversion(random.Next(80, 120), random.NextItem(x.Units)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I completly forgot about Enumerable.Range ... Thank you!